# Iteration over an object

Tags: php

- I need some help please regarding PDOStatement::commit (from phpnet manual)
- I don't understand Example #1, because of this part of the code:

  ```
  foreach ($fruits as $fruit) {  
      $sth->execute(array(  
          $fruit->name,  
          $fruit->colour,  
          $fruit->calories,  
      )
  );
  ```

1#
- Does it iterate over an object, array or what?
- I've tried both ... and of course, both give errors
- Definitely, the -> operator tells me that it's an object, but I still don't understand the syntax.
- It is possible to iterate/acces simultaneously more than one property of an object?
2#
- When it is said "Insert multiple records...", I understand "more than one row", am I wrong?

- Thank you.

Comment: It probably iterates over an [`\Iterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php).

Comment: Why do you write in list items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They iterate over array `$fruits` apparently. It is declared and filled out of scope of given code snippet. The `$fruits` contains object with given field. Do create a class, then fill `$fruits`. "When it is said "Insert multiple records...", I understand "more than one row", am I wrong?" - it means from 0 to N rows.

Comment: - Thank you, I'll try it, I do not master English so well :0), but now it's all clear in my head, do the array, do fill it with objects. Well ... it seems I'm not so clever ... thank you again for your very useful and precise answer